# C# Mapping struct in ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, struct, nhibernate-mapping, castle-activerecord

i am making a little application to help me balance my checkbook.
i am using Castle ActiveRecord to map the object properties to the database. now here is the problem. as i am making a money program i made a struct Currency

The struct:

```
public struct Currency
{
    private long amount;
    private CurrencyType currencyType;

    public long Amount
    {
        get { return this.amount; }
        set { this.amount = value; }
    }

    public CurrencyType CurrencyType
    {
        get { return this.currencyType; }
        set { this.currencyType = value; }
    }
}
```

The class i am mapping:

```
[ActiveRecord("[Transaction]")]
public class Transaction: HasOwnerModelBase
{
    private Currency amount;
    private Category category;

    [BelongsTo]
    public virtual Category Category
    {
        get { return this.category; }
        set { this.category = value; }
    }

    public virtual Currency Amount
    {
        get { return this.amount; }
        set { this.amount = value; }
    }
}
```

Now in the ideal situation the Currency object would act like a nested object so the amount and currencyType are two colums in the transaction table.
but it is not a nested seeing as i want it to act like the currency struct object.

I have no idea what tag i should give the Currency Amount for it to work, i would really appreciate it if any one could help me solve this problem.

I hope all of this is clear.

Greatings Duncan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following? Or didn't I get the question? Note that I changed the structure to a class because you need virtual members for dynamic proxy generation and you cannot have virtual members on structures. By the way, why don't you use auto-implemented properties?

```
public class Currency
{
    [Property]
    public virtual Int64 Amount { get; set; }   

    [Property]
    public virtual CurrencyType CurrencyType { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("[Transaction]")]
public class Transaction: HasOwnerModelBase
{
    [BelongsTo]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Nested]  
    public virtual Currency Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well the virtual stuff i know my bad but not really important for this example.
the auto property thing is that at work we still have to use the vs2005 so not used to it yet ;)

the nested is indeed a good idea but i already tough of that. i can't really test it now, but i am pretty sure that the object is get when i pull a transaction from the database is not a currency object. if so. i am really stupid

Comment: It should be an instance of your Currency class or of a dynamic proxy derived from Currency depending on whether you are using transparent lazy loading or not.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow when i can test it properly. will update thanx for the help so fare!

Comment: +1 Nested is the way to go. BTW I don't think components are proxied.